Relative position when settings up a coordinate system, using the position of a quantum entity that is in a position superposition?
I am a bit confused about one aspect of quantum mechanics. I recognize that a particle does not necessarily (or ever) exist in one position eigenstate. Rather, it exists simultaneously in a linear combination of many position eigenstates. However, that position eigenstate is measured relative to the observer. However, if I were to set up a reference frame using the particle's "position", suddenly, the positions in the rest of the universe become uncertain. Am I correct on that count? If so, how would you set up a coordinate system while still considering the fuzziness of the positions in the universe without using expected values or some other technique that loses the detailed information of the specific uncertainty in each position? Is there also a way to extend this with time uncertainty?

When you say "a reference frame using the particle's position" do you mean that if you have some particle with wave function $\psi(\mathbf{x})$ that you go to a frame such that $\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{0}$? If so, then this is done in scattering theory, where you have two interacting particles. Then it is usual to describe it in relative distances $\mathbf{r} = |\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'|$. Other than that I see no other reasons to make such a coordinate transformation, as $\mathbf{x}$ is the coordinate at which we evaluate $\psi$ and not the particle's position.

I mean making a transformation from the observer's reference frame to the particle's reference frame, such that you can describe the point in space with a vector space that still accounts for the probabilistic nature of the position (and time). I am asking how such a coordinate transformation works because, theoretically, everything is made of particles, so all observer's notions of time and position are fuzzy.

You cannot make a coordinate transformation to the particle's reference frame if the particle is described by some wave function. Because we don't know where the particle is. For example, think of a momentum eigenstate in some volume, which is very delocalized. Then the particle's frame of reference could be literally any point in our volume.

Thank you. This is quite helpful.

I think most of us would take the particle's position to be described by its probability density function i.e. the modulus squared of its wavefunction. While it's true that the wavefunction can be written as a superposition of position eigenstates it's not obvious that this is a useful thing to do.
If we were setting up the rest frame of the particle, so we could measure other positions relative to it, we would choose the origin of the frame to be at the expectation value of the particle position. Then there is no fuzziness associated with the coordinate system - it just means the particle remains in a superposition of position eigenstates even in its rest frame.

Thanks for clarifying this. I see that it would probably not be a good idea to use coordinates relative to a super positioned particle. However, I would still like to see if there is a method to measure positions relative to the super positioned particle. Is there such a method that keeps the fuzziness of a coordinate system that is based on a probablistic position?
